# How To Get data in report depend on app_user in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table call EVENTS which has the Events details(id,event name,event type,date,location,user_id).

When I log in to the app and go to the event page, I want to be able to see only my events and each user see his events only.

I am using

````
       EVENTS.EVENT,
       EVENTS.EVENT_TYPE,
       EVENTS.LOCATION,
       EVENTS.EVENT_OWNER,
       EVENTS.EVENT_DATE,
       EVENTS.USER_ID
  from EVENTS
  WHERE EVENTS.USER_ID= :APP_USER_ID; ```
but it is not giving me the desired result.It give me no data found 
Can anyone help me, please?
````

Answer (score 1):

The correct substitution string for the application user that is currently logged on is `:APP_USER` (not APP_USER_ID ). Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html#GUID-34118202-1B85-4D38-8C27-F819679504DB) for a list of all built-in substitution strings. Note that the variable APP_USER contains the user*name* in upper case.

If the column events.user_id contains the APP_USER values, the following should work fine.

```
WHERE EVENTS.USER_ID= :APP_USER
```

--update after comment--

I cannot see your data so cannot solve it for you. It's your environment and your data and you are the only one who can see it. If you want help then provide as much info as possible. A sentence "i tried x and get no data found" is of no help. I cannot see your data nor run a query on your application.
What is the relationship between the value in APP_USER and values in the column EVENTS.USER_ID ? That is something you have to research. You can do some debugging, for example by creating a report, just for debug purposes with the source

```
SELECT events.user_id as user_id,
       :APP_USER as app_user 
  FROM events FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

That will give you the value for APP_USER and info about what is in EVENTS.USER_ID. If the 2 don't match then you'll never get any rows.

Comment: i have been used (where upper( user_name )= upper(:app_user)); but also gave me no data found.

Comment: How can I send a photo to my table in a comment?

Comment: Update your question with any relevant information. Attachments are not encouraged because they can be malicious

Answer (score 1):

As Koen explained, APP_USER_ID is not a substitution string. However, from the column name, I understand that you are storing User ID on your table, not the user name. Therefore, you need a inner select for your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENTS.USER_ID= (select ID from apex_users where username = :APP_USER);
```